# Log dbus Desktop Notifications

Tags: d-bus, freedesktop, libnotify

Sometimes I get error messages in desktop notifications, such as this:

[image: VBoxClient: the VirtualBox kernel service is not running. Exiting.]

Unfortunately, it's difficult to debug this. I can't use `xprop` to see the process id that sent it. It claims to be from VBoxClient, but I can't tell for sure. I can't even copy the text in the notification bubble. The best I can do is take a screenshot.

Is there some way to log desktop notifications to `/var/log/messages` or otherwise get information about the process that sent it, or at least the text of the notification itself?

Comment: You could try to monitor the notification service with e.g. `dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'`

Comment: But there's no way to see prior messages, correct? You have to run that at login and then keep it running constantly?

Comment: yes... afaik.. it's not even guaranteed you'll get anything outta that; for ex. with gnome-shell as the shell has its own notification service/system the above will not output anything... so best bet would probably be to listen to all notification services and log every message